# Spring MVC resources, how to update once uploaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble with updating my spring mvc css resource, once uploaded to deploy directory it don't take any changes. I tried to fix it using maven clean->compile->deploy, then run tomcat server. But changes don't appear deployed app still using old css...In deployed .war package new css appeared.

servlet-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sping.test.controller"/>

    <bean class=
                  "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Comment: trying clearing your browser's cache

Comment: @SleimanJneidi helped thanks)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem normally I use one variable with timestamp value in the css/js url, like this

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css?${applicationScope['cacheHash']}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/homeMenu.css?${applicationScope['cacheHash']}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
```

The problem is you need to declare this **${applicationScope['cacheHash']}** in the scope application on the server, you can declare in any Listerner.

```
public class CacheListener implements ServletContextListener {
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("cacheHash", new Date().getTime());
}
```